# datastax cassandra query result decoding in php

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra and using the Datastax PHP CQL.

Given the following query, how should I decode the result?

```
$cql = SELECT * FROM  company WHERE userid = 1001 ORDER BY gpsTime DESC LIMIT 1;                           
$statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement($cql);
$result = $this->session->execute($statement);
```

I tried decoding with:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    // Get values from row and add to array
    array_push($allVehicleInfo,array(
        'userID'    => $row['userid']->value,
        'gpsTime'   => $row['gpstime']->seconds,
         'latitude' => $row['latitude']->value )
    );
}
```

However, I get an error:

> Message: Undefined property: Cassandra\Decimal::$value

---

My table schema is:

```
$cql = "CREATE TABLE " company " (
    userID bigint,
    userName ascii,
    latitude decimal,
    longitude decimal,
    accuracy float,
    altitude float,
    gpsTime timestamp );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a function and not property, so you'll have to do `$row['latitude']->value()`

Answer (score 0):

As Alex has said, in your example `value` is not a property. Instead please check the documentation of the class you're trying to decode. [The documentation can be found here](https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/).

If you are not sure which class you're dealing with, you can use the in-build function `get_class()` - [see get_class() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php).

Once you know what class you're dealing with you can check the DataStax PHP Driver documentation to see which function you need to call to retrieve the correct value.

For example if you were dealing with a `Cassandra\Timestamp` class, you would have to call the `time()` function to retrieve the time as an `int`. [See Timestamp documentation](https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/class.Timestamp/).

In your case, you're likely dealing with a `Float`, so check [the Float documentation](https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/class.Float/) and see that you need to call function `value()` to retrieve a `float` value of the `Cassandra\Float` instance.

---

Code solution:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    // Get values from row and add to array
    array_push($allVehicleInfo,array(
        'userID'    => $row['userid']->value(),
        'gpsTime'   => $row['gpstime']->seconds,
         'latitude' => $row['latitude']->value() )
    );
}
```